# Use framed package with marginpar

Tags: marginpar

I would like to emphasize a text block and still be able to use margin paragraphs.

A non-MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{color} 

\usepackage{framed} 
\renewenvironment{shaded}{% 
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{shadecolor}}% 
\MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore\FrameRestore}% 
\noindent}% 
{\endMakeFramed\noindent}% 
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85} 

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1] 

\begin{shaded} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \marginpar{Lorem?} 
\lipsum[1-4] 
\end{shaded} 

\lipsum[7] 

\end{document}
```

How to tweak it to allow the `marginpar` without loosing the ability for a pagebreak across the emphasized text block? A do not need to use `framed` if other options are available, but the use of `marginpar` is required in the original document, where `marginfix` is used.

Comment: Is `framed` breakable at all? Use `mdframe` or `tcolorbox` in conjunction with `marginnote` package, for example

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: `framed` is perfectly breakable. It even cooperates fine with `ntheorem` to define `framedtheorem` or `shadedtheorem` environments.

Comment: @Bernard: I see. I never used it really

Answer (score 2):

Load the `marginnote` package, it works fine in a float environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{marginnote} \usepackage{framed}
\renewenvironment{shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore\FrameRestore}%
\noindent}%
{\endMakeFramed\noindent}%
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{shaded}
\lipsum[1-3]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \marginnote{\color{red}\bfseries Lorem?}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{shaded}

\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `marginnote` does not work for me. I utilize `marginfix` in the original document.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work with the very code I posted? Perhaps there's some incompatibility between `marginfix` (which I never used) and `marginnote`?